# I have a shrub west of the house and I don't know what it is

Tags: identification

There is a shrub that came with the house a few years ago and it is in the western part of the house. It grows in North Carolina and is on cypress and cedar mulch. This shrub doesn't flower, and the leaves turn red or brown during fall.
[image: Unknown Shrub]

---

Close Up view:
[image: Close Up View]

Comment: Where is the shrub located, what part of the world...

Comment: Located at the western part of the house, North Carolina, United states.